# Eliminate consumed capacity alarm from CDK created dynamodb tables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

Using `cdk` I have created a `dynamodb` with scaling props:

```
// create table

Table myTable = dynamodb.Table.Builder...

// read scaling props

EnableScalingProps myReadScalingProps = EnableScalingProps.builder.minCapacity(10)...

myTable.autoScaleReadCapacity(myReadScalingProps)

// utilization scaling

myTable.scaleOnUtilization(
  UtilizationScalingProps.builder.targetUtlizationPercent(50).build)
)
```

This is automatically creating a Cloudwatch Alarm that checks when the `ConsumedReadCapacityUnits` is below a threshold.  This alarm creates a lot of "noise" in my Cloudwatch dashboard.

**How do I prevent such alarms from automatically being created by CDK?**

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Comment: Target tracking scaling policies are based on CloudWatch alarms created and managed by Application Auto Scaling. I don't think you can disable those alarms if you want to keep the auto-scaling capability. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-target-tracking.html

Comment: Regarding the noise - there is a `Hide Auto Scaling alarms` checkbox on the Alarms page in CloudWatch console that should do the trick. You cannot remove them since the alarms are used by autoscaling to decide when to initiate scaling in/out.